# Woocommerce Add product attribute on category page

Tags: woocommerce

I am looking to add a product attribute under the Product Title for each product, when listed on the category page.

I know I can use the woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_product_category_attribute', 10 );
function custom_product_category_test() {
        echo '<div class="product-test">ATTRIBUTE HERE</div>';
}
```

However, is it possible to "extract" the attribute from the product? It will always be the size attribute and every product has this attribute.